# Devolver las propiedades de un objeto que cumplan una condición y guardarlas en una variable- Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, javascript-objeto

Como hago para almacenar en diferentes variables diferentes datos solicitados en mongodb?
Esta es la estructura de mi colección

```
    {
    title: {
       type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true, 
        unique: true },
    compra: {
      type: Number,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    venta: {
      type: Number,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

Por ejemplo: Del objeto que tenga como propiedad el title "dolar", necesito el valor de su propiedad "compra".

Este es el codigo que probe para almacenar ese dato

```
Import Task from "/task"; 


export async function buscarValorDolar(req, res) {

  const tituloDolar = await Task.filter(task => task.title === 'dolar');
  var precioCompraDolar = await Task.forEach(tituloDolar.compra);
 
}

export var precioCompraDolar;
```

al usar la variable precioCompraDolar me arroja Undefined.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], además, puedes leer [mcve]. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Dónde tienes problemas? ¿Puedes mostrart un ejemplo del resultado esperado? Haz clic en [edit] y agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, de lo contrario podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por las aclaraciones, ya lo edité!